# Android TV самостоятельно переключает язык на язык системы

Tags: android, locale, android-jetpack-compose, android-tv

Ситуация следующая, есть приложение под AndroidTV написано на Compose. В приложении можно сменить язык. Проблема в том что иногда не понятно почему язык откатывается до системного сам по себе. Смогли воспроизвести подобный баг следующим образом. У нас есть библиотека, чтобы открывать видео с ютуба, вот эта:com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer, если через неё открыть видео а потом закрыть его, приложение поменяет язык обратно на установленный в системе.
Кто-то сталкивался с подобным? В чём может быть дело?